# how can i assign the hash code of any object into the instance veriable of the same object?

Tags: java-me

how can i assign the hash code of any object into the instance veriable of the same object at compile time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Objects don't exist at compile time.

Comment: how can i do the same at run time? as the objects creates all the hash code of these objects should be stored in the instance veriable array?

Comment: I think you really need to state your question better. What exactly are you trying to do? what is the "instance variable array" you mention - you never mentioned an array previously.

If for instance you want an array with the hash of a series of objects, then you just need to store the hash in the array as you create the objects.